# Cannot find libcublas.so.9.0 when running TensorBoard as sudo

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I can run TensorBoard as non-root user successfully. For some reason I have
to use a port number with need root permission. So I need to run TensorBoard using sudo command. Then the error message comes out:

> cannot find libcublas.so.9.0.

I am sure `libcublas.so.9.0` is there under `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`. If I run `sudo echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the first library path will just be `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, so I do not know what to do.

I am using CUDA 9.0, TensorFlow 1.7, Python 2.7 with Anaconda.